# Absolute positioned div with higher z-index is displayed under other divs

Tags: html, css, z-index, css-position

I have an HTML code with an error at some point that I cannot detect. Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gteEg/1/).

In particular, when I move on "Show more", an absolute positioned div with highest z-index should be shown on top of everything. However, as you may see the first absolute positioned div is shown under other content.
As provided in answers from similar questions, I already set a `z-index` value and the `position` type (*absolute* or *relative*) for each container of the `div`.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: once remove all z-index and check. I hope you will get your solution

Comment: Well, if I set the z-index value (e.g. 1000) only to the div with class **detail-modal-window**, everything works fine. The problem is that its container should be set with a z-index value (e.g. 10), but the browser seems to ignore that 10 < 1000!

Comment: @GhostAnswer Thanks, I solved following your suggestions and by using z-index:auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **[Ghost Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/968866/ghost-answer)** comment, I solved the problem.

In other answers I read that one should put an *increasing z-index* value as well a `position:relative` to all the containers of a div that one would show on hover. Maybe it isn't always true.
Here is what I did:

1. I removed all the z-index values and unnecessary positioning (I suppose the latter is not meaningful).
2. I set `z-index:auto` to the container of the div that I would to show on hover.

Now the code works fine: this is the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gteEg/11/).

Answer (score 0):

try this css

```
 .offer-info-shops span
position:absolute;
z-index:1000;
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gteEg/2/)

Comment: Sorry, but It doesn't work! Did you tried it? Can you please show me a working JSFiddle?

Comment: It doesn't work. Have you seen that the second "Show more" is shown on top? To highlight this problem, get a look at the same [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gteEg/3/) with a white background for the absolute positioned div

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem.

Change the following z-indices:

```
.offer-content, .offer-content-info-shops{z-index:auto}
```

```
.detail-modal-window{z-index:1}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gteEg/12/

By doing this, all the elements have their z-indices compared against each other.

The issue you had was because since you assigned a z-index to offer-content, and .offer-content-info-shops, you had created a stack context, meaning that child elements of .offer-content-info such as .detail-modal-window had their z-index compared to its siblings in .offer-content-info-shops.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index

Comment: After I posted my solution, the page updated and then I saw your solution. Good job figuring it out.